# Webpack: transpiling of assets transferred to dist directory using copy-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, plugins, lazy-loading

I am integrating an SPA built predominantly using d3.js into Webpack. I'm transpiling with Babel, and using the latest versions of everything..

Before integration, d3.js allowed me (event-driven) to inject scripts dynamically, entirely reusably, recursively and hence effortlessly into the served-up html file. The only thing I had to provide were the foundational JSON files.

For example (just for info, not critical to understanding the question), for a menu-building javascript file:

```
case "js":
  files_to_attach
  .insert("script") // --> inject into html file
  .attr("src", function() {
    return "frontend/" + filetype + "/" + menu_group + "/" + menu + "/" + filename + "." + filetype;
  })
  .attr("type", "text/javascript") // Also tried using type "module" here
  .attr("class", menu)
  .attr("id", menu_item);
break;
```

This approach was used across all loaded assets.

Webpack has it's own mechanisms for dynamic loading, but I chose (by importing all external scripts, then selecting, on-demand, from their assigned constant names) to stick with the above, again direct-injecting them into the dist/index.html file.

I did this so that these loading actions can, in the future, be easily converted to database calls.

To allow all this to happen, I had to transfer the scripts en bloc *from* the frontend (normally 'src') *to* the dist directory using the 'copy-webpack-plugin'.

This differs from the [prescribed Webpack lazy loading](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/) approach in that these scripts are external to, rather than an integral part of, index.js.

The problem? These files still contain the untranspiled import statements, provoking the following:

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

These import statements lie, needless to say, at the head of each module.

**The question, then, is:**

Given the scripts are correctly injected into the final html, how do I ensure they are also (pre- or post-) transpiled?

The configuration is simple and the question a general one, so to show more code seems superfluous. I imagine there may be a few approaches to this.

**SUMMARY THUS FAR**

Webpack ruthlessly blocks all attempts at non-'import'-or-'require'-style file system access, but neither import nor require can return a direct reference to a file (as opposed to the file's contents). So import statements (which **do** lead to transpiling) cannot be leveraged to inject a script to HTML.

Script injections using libraries such as d3.js are simply left un-transpiled. Is there some means of 'force'-transpiling them?

The only documented means of script injection is **effectively** static, using multiple entry points. Furthermore, no plugin seems to exist that can assist with dynamic script injection. (The nearest I've found to a solution is inject-html-webpack-plugin, but the plugin's documentation is brutally terse, with no example of so-called 'transducer' use).

Truly dynamic, transpiled script injection into HTML seems blocked on all fronts.

No files copied using copy-webpack-plugin are transpiled, but do I see mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56093213/transpiling-and-linting-files-outside-of-my-root-directory-webpack-4?rq=1) of a tortuous workaround ("copy the files from the src files into the module, process them and then move the generated/processed files").

Answer (score 0):

`copy-webpack-plugin` is literally a `fs.move` command. Since some plugins run first than loaders, specially in this case, they aren't being transpiled.

To do that you'll have to add the external files as a new entrypoint, where the source code is going to be generated and created at the end, and you can add them to index as well

Comment: Multiple problems unrelated to your answer. Webpack only outputs to the internal defaults (main.js), completely ignores naming customisations. Hashing doesn't work, so multiple entry points can't be processed. On attempted execution, correctly processed imports in dynamically injected files can no longer be located.

Comment: Found several circular dependencies (big code base). Taking steps to eliminate them.

Comment: If you customize to [name].js on output, it will output given entry point names

Comment: As mentioned above, webpack completely ignores naming customizations. Tried many hashing modules targeting for example [name], [contenthash], [id], [chunkhash] etc. None work.

Comment: o "add the external files as a new entrypoint": where a new entry point is specified, the file to be injected is loaded too early, missing essential HTML hooks and parameter values. If missing, the omitted transpiling provokes a "SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module"

Comment: "where the source code is going to be generated and created at the end". **How**?

Comment: "and you can add them to index [presumably js file] as well" - has no effect on imported file.

Comment: You say some plugins run before loaders (which seems a bit strange). Is there some way of forcing loaders to run first?